# How to fetch and checkout in Git at once?

Tags: git, git-checkout, git-fetch

I use git version 1.7.7.5.

Is that possible to do the following using one git command?

```
git fetch git@github.com:someone/repo.git someones_branch
git checkout FETCH_HEAD -b my_testing_branch
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you can set the upstream branch of my_testing_branch

```
git branch --set-upstream my_testing_branch someone/someone_branch
```

(here using a remote named 'someone')

And simply git pull on it (but that would still require: `git checkout my_testing_branch` + `git pull`)

To answer your question, one way would be to define a [git alias](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Git/aliases)

```
git config --global alias.fetch-github '"!f() { git fetch git@github.com:$1/$2.git $3 ; git checkout FETCH_HEAD -b $4 }; f"'
```

You would use it like so:

```
git fetch-github someone repo someone_branch my_testing_branch
```